# Is it possible to create Azure policy on a specific resource group ID or name

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Need to create a policy in azure which should have an option to filter resource groups based on resource group ID or name. During policy assignment I should get an option to provide resource group ID or name in the Parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to filter Resource Groups as Exclusions while creating Azure Policy. Please check the following screenshot. You can select the Resource groups to be excluded

[image]
Thanks,
Manu